# Question marked as duplicate and downvoted

Tags: discussion, down-votes

Recently, I **believe** that one of my questions was treated in an aggressive way by one of the respected users of SO. I do not have proofs, just the fact that all the three things happened roughly around the same time, but the question was edited (fine for me), a slightly rude comment was posted (I only consider it rude because of the combination of the things which happened around) and the questions was closed and marked as a duplicate (the duplicate of the questions the editor made himself 4 years after I posted mine, with his own answer). I am wondering what could be the reasons for treating like that my manuscript.

Comment: How do you know that particular user downvoted your question? Do you have any proof for that?

Comment: It just a suspicion, as I am around the SO for the whole day and those three things happened almost at the same time..

Comment: Please note that this is not the Meta for Stack Overflow. Even then, you have zero way of knowing who down voted your question. There is tons of traffic on SO, so please don't name and shame someone. You're likely wrong. The comment is completely correct, signing posts here is unnecessary. As you can see, you have an ID box next to your post. It's standard to delete such things but I doubt that's why it was downvoted.

Comment: @Catija I believe in numbers and the probability of someone else doing this is very low..

Comment: It's irrelevant. Making bald-faced claims that have no supporting evidence is only going to do damage to you. You would be better served asking for general guidance for how to avoid this in the future, which I'm sure already exists on MSO, so do some searching before asking about it. In general, the users don't take kindly to meta posts where someone complains about another user. We prefer meta to be constructive, asking for help and improvement.

Comment: @Catija, thank you for clarifying, since I have not really participated on meta, my understanding of what is it about is wrong. I will update the question.

Comment: @Serhiy the question is off topic here, no matter how you edit it. It's about specific question from Stack Overflow, which got its own meta site.

Comment: You can however prevent further downvotes by removing the name calling and false assumptions in your question.

Comment: @ShadowWizard It is fine for me, I am not rep grinding machine who will be crying for some virtual reward. I just want to help people, treat them respectfully and receive the same treatment.

Comment: @Serhiy Your question demonstrates a complete lack of respect for other people.  Saying that you just want to help people and treat them respectfully doesn't really mean anything when you actually do the opposite.

Comment: @Serhiy cheers, I respect that and hope Patrick's answer helped you understand things better. As for removing the signature it's totally legit, many people are editing these out all the time to keep the post clean and to the point.

Comment: @Servy with exception of misunderstanding initially the purpose of the site, tell me where am I disrespectful? Whom should I contact in case I feel that my efforts are being destroyed?

Comment: @ShadowWizard I agree, have nothing against people editing my posts, but as I told, it was the combination of factors happening at the same time which made it look more agressive that it was.. In my opinion.

Comment: @Serhiy well, if it's the first time you have a question closed I can totally understand. Anyway, I oppose the closure as well, but just because the other question is closed too, hence no way to add more answers in either of them. Generally speaking, closing as duplicate is not a bad sign.

Comment: @Serhiy You're insulting someone for improving your question, pointing you to an existing answer of that question, and helping you understand how to effectively utilize the site, and accusing them (without evidence) of providing feedback as to the quality of the question that you personally don't like.  Even in your very own comment by stating that "your efforts are being destroyed" when *nothing* of yours has been destroyed at all.

Answer (score 8):

I guess you mean this comment on the edit:

> NEVER sign your questions, the system already does that for you, this is not a forum.

A: that comment is not rude. B: usually it is not a reason for downvoting. C: you *assume* he downvoted you, but you have no proof of that at all. Of course, your question won't have much users passing by since it is an old question, but still.

Closing a question as a duplicate isn't bad, even if it is your own or after a long time. The point is (and I can't judge that): is it really a duplicate or not? If not, you could ping the user to ask to reopen it. Else you can edit your post to explain why it isn't a duplicate.

Comment: I agree the comment itself is not rude, but considering the combination of the things, even if it was not him downvoting, marking as duplicate as exactly his questions.. This seemed like an aggressive move..

Comment: To close a question as duplicate? That is considered helpful in my opinion...

Comment: Reposting comment from the SO question: still doesn't justify closing, and honestly it looks like not-so-valid attempt of Jarrod to draw attention to his failed canonical experiment. (Failed since it's closed.)

Comment: I agree it doesn't look nice, but I can't really judge that. If it really is foul play, OP should flag the question for moderation attention.

Comment: No moderator is needed, just to reopen. He won't be able to close again, problem solved.

Comment: If someone is deliberately using his close vote powers to close a question by himself to attract attention to his own post, that is something for moderators @Sha.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Only if the question isn't actually a suitable duplicate.

Comment: Of course......

Comment: Agree with @Servy here, there are valid canonical questions on SO, my point all the time here was that the target question was closed, hence not proper dupe target.

Comment: @ShadowWizard A question being closed doesn't necessarily mean that it's not a valid dup target.  A question not having an answer that answers the question (well) makes it an invalid dup target.